# Display Javasciprt file's data on a Razor page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a javascript file in which I have an array of object. I want to display the content of that array on a razor page. My question is how to access a javascript file's content in a razor page.
This is my cshtml file.

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "HOME PAGE";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GameLayout.cshtml";
}

<div id="Display"></div>
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/leaderboard.js" type="module"></script>
    <script>
        var data = '';
        @* console.log(array,"array") *@
        for (var key in array) {
            if (array[key].a != undefined) {
                data += '<span>' + array[key].a +  '</span> ';
            }
            if (array[key].b != undefined) {
                data += '<span>' + array[key].b + '</span> ';
            }
            if (array[key].c != undefined) {
                data += '<span>' + array[key].c + '</span> ';
            }
        }

        $("#Display").html(data);
    </script>
}
```

This is my JavaScript file.

```
let array =
    [{ a: 53 },
    { b: 31 },
    { c: 15 }]

console.log(array,"array")
```

I want to display the content of array in html tags.

When I console.log array from the leaderboard.js file it is printing the array but when I console .log it from cshtml it says that array is not defined.

Comment: How do you want to display the array? Display on the table or any other format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how do you want to display the array, here is a simple demo about how to display the array data:

```
<div id="Display"></div>
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/leaderboard.js"></script>
    <script>
        var data = '';
        for (var key in array) {
            if (array[key].a != undefined) {
                data += '<span>' + array[key].a +  '</span> ';
            }
            if (array[key].b != undefined) {
                data += '<span>' + array[key].b + '</span> ';
            }
            if (array[key].c != undefined) {
                data += '<span>' + array[key].c + '</span> ';
            }
        }

        $("#Display").html(data);
    </script>
}
```

**Update:**

Please remove `type="module"` in your razor pages.

Reference:

https://javascript.info/modules-intro#module-level-scope

Comment: I'm getting this error. Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined at leaderboard:31

Comment: Hi @M.HassanNasir, be sure you have defined array in leaderboard.js. And my js code above is in the razor pages. Please share more code to us.

Comment: kindly check my question again I have updated it. I'm facing this issue right now.
When I console.log array from the leaderboard.js file it is printing the array but when I console .log it from cshtml file's script section it says that array is not defined.

Comment: It works well in my project. Please check leaderboard.js file if it is in `wwwroot/js` folder. Maybe share a simple code repo will be more helpful.

Comment: leaderboard.js file is indeed in the wwwroot/js folder. I am importing it correctly because in my leaderboard.cshtml I can see the array in my console, which I consoled in my js file but when I console array from cshtml file's script section it says it is undefined.

Comment: Hi @M.HassanNasir, Please remove `type="module"` in your razor pages.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Thanks for all the help :) I will try to give you a code sample.

Comment: Ok. Waiting for your response.

Comment: I was trying to import another js file in my leaderboard.js which was causing this error now I have removed it and it's working completely fine. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hi @M.HassanNasir, I saw you unmark the answer. Did you still have issue?